# How to set the value of an attribute according to the values of other attributes in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, innodb

I am trying to set the value of an attribute according to other attributes' values.

I have the following SQL statement,

```
SELECT C.course_name, C.language, C.course_price, C.average_rating, C.category, P.name, P.surname, D.percentage, D.start_date, D.end_date, D.is_allowed
FROM course C LEFT OUTER JOIN discount D ON C.course_id=D.discounted_course_id, course_creator CC, person P
WHERE C.course_creator_id=CC.course_creator_id AND CC.course_creator_id=P.person_id
```

I have the following result,

[image]

Expected Result is the same as above, HOWEVER, the first row's course_price is 500.

I want to set the course_price according to the followings:

If current day is less than end_date and is_allowed = 1, Then I want to apply the discount percentage to the course_price. For instance since course_price of the first tuple is 1000, percentage is 50, (let's say end_date is bigger than today's date), and is_allowed=1. Then the course_price should be equal to 500.

Course Relation:

[image]

Course Creator Relation:

[image]

Discount Relation:

[image]

Person Relation:

[image]

I want to get All courses with their information and set the course_price of these courses to the discounted price if the discount relation has the course_id of the course and is_allowed is 1, and the end_date of the discount is bigger than today's date

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Don't mix explicit JOIN's with implicit, comma separated ones. Too confusing. Use explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere.

Comment: Could you review again? I did provide sample data.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also, simplify if possible, i.e. [mcve].

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If current day is less than end_date and is_allowed = 1, Then I want to apply the discount percentage to the course_price.

You seem to want a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT C.course_name, C.language, C.course_price, C.average_rating, C.category,
     P.name, P.surname,
     D.percentage, D.start_date, D.end_date, D.is_allowed,
     (CASE WHEN current_date < D.end_date and D.is_allowed
           THEN C.course_price * D.percentage
           ELSE c.course_price
      END) as imputed_price
FROM course C LEFT OUTER JOIN
    discount D 
    ON C.course_id = D.discounted_course_id LEFT JOIN
    course_creator CC
    ON C.course_creator_id = CC.course_creator_id LEFT JOIN
    person P
    ON CC.course_creator_id = P.person_id;
```

Note that this also fixes the `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use comma in the `FROM` clause!

Comment: What should I do if I want to add filter to the imputed_price. I tried adding 
WHERE imputed_price <= 1000, however, the imputed_price is not known.

Comment: @MustafaYaşar . . . A simple method is a CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF or CASE(SQL92 compatible) function for that. Many RDBMSs have it.

Here is an example for MySql taken from [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php):

```
SELECT book_name,
IF(pub_lang='English',"English Book","Other Language") 
AS Language 
FROM book_mast;
```

The data:

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| book_id | book_name                           | isbn_no     | cate_id | aut_id | pub_id | dt_of_pub  | pub_lang | no_page | book_price |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| BK001   | Introduction to Electrodynamics     | 0000979001  | CA001   | AUT001 | P003   | 2001-05-08 | English  |     201 |      85.00 |
| BK002   | Understanding of Steel Construction | 0000979002  | CA002   | AUT002 | P001   | 2003-07-15 | English  |     300 |     105.50 |
| BK003   | Guide to Networking                 | 0000979003  | CA003   | AUT003 | P002   | 2002-09-10 | Hindi    |     510 |     200.00 |
| BK004   | Transfer  of Heat and Mass          | 0000979004  | CA002   | AUT004 | P004   | 2004-02-16 | English  |     600 |     250.00 |
| BK005   | Conceptual Physics                  | 0000979005  | CA001   | AUT005 | P006   | 2003-07-16 | NULL     |     345 |     145.00 |
| BK006   | Fundamentals of Heat                | 0000979006  | CA001   | AUT006 | P005   | 2003-08-10 | German   |     247 |     112.00 |
| BK007   | Advanced 3d Graphics                | 0000979007  | CA003   | AUT007 | P002   | 2004-02-16 | Hindi    |     165 |      56.00 |
| BK008   | Human Anatomy                       | 0000979008  | CA005   | AUT008 | P006   | 2001-05-17 | German   |      88 |      50.50 |
| BK009   | Mental Health Nursing               | 0000979009  | CA005   | AUT009 | P007   | 2004-02-10 | English  |     350 |     145.00 |
| BK010   | Fundamentals of Thermodynamics      | 0000979010  | CA002   | AUT010 | P007   | 2002-10-14 | English  |     400 |     225.00 |
| BK011   | The Experimental Analysis of Cat    | 0000979011  | CA004   | AUT011 | P005   | 2007-06-09 | French   |     225 |      95.00 |
| BK012   | The Nature  of World                | 0000979012  | CA004   | AUT005 | P008   | 2005-12-20 | English  |     350 |      88.00 |
| BK013   | Environment a Sustainable Future    | 0000979013  | CA004   | AUT012 | P001   | 2003-10-27 | German   |     165 |     100.00 |
| BK014   | Concepts in Health                  | 0000979014  | CA005   | AUT013 | P004   | 2001-08-25 | NULL     |     320 |     180.00 |
| BK015   | Anatomy & Physiology                | 0000979015  | CA005   | AUT014 | P008   | 2000-10-10 | Hindi    |     225 |     135.00 |
| BK016   | Networks and Telecommunications     | 00009790_16 | CA003   | AUT015 | P003   | 2002-01-01 | French   |      95 |      45.00 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
```

The result:

```
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| book_name                           | Language       |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Introduction to Electrodynamics     | Engllish Book  | 
| Understanding of Steel Construction | Engllish Book  | 
| Guide to Networking                 | Other Lnaguage | 
| Transfer  of Heat and Mass          | Engllish Book  | 
| Conceptual Physics                  | Other Lnaguage | 
| Fundamentals of Heat                | Other Lnaguage | 
| Advanced 3d Graphics                | Other Lnaguage | 
| Human Anatomy                       | Other Lnaguage | 
| Mental Health Nursing               | Engllish Book  | 
| Fundamentals of Thermodynamics      | Engllish Book  | 
| The Experimental Analysis of Cat    | Other Lnaguage | 
| The Nature  of World                | Engllish Book  | 
| Environment a Sustainable Future    | Other Lnaguage | 
| Concepts in Health                  | Other Lnaguage | 
| Anatomy & Physiology                | Other Lnaguage | 
| Networks and Telecommunications     | Other Lnaguage | 
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: "*Many RDBMS have it*"? - I think it's only MySQL that supports the non-standard `IF()` - all RDBMS support the standard `CASE` expression however.

Comment: In case there is no "IF", you can use "CASE".

Comment: @AbylaySabirgaliyev sir I am aware that I should IF or CASE, but how?

Comment: @MustafaYaşar by providing the function with an expression and the results. Read a bit into it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I see no exact RDBMS in your question I will give you a query that *should* work in mssql server (please note, that I could not verify the query with exact data so I might have typos).

In mssql you can convert selects to updates quite easily. Probably in other databases too.

```sql
UPDATE C
SET course_price = course_price * ((100-percentage) / 100)
FROM course C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN discount D ON C.course_id=D.discounted_course_id, 
course_creator CC, person P
WHERE C.course_creator_id=CC.course_creator_id 
    AND CC.course_creator_id=P.person_id
    AND end_date < GETDATE()
    AND is_allowed = 1
    AND C.course_id = course.course_id -- course is the table in the update statement
```